# Can I invoke Scala dynamic functions from Groovy?

Tags: java, scala, gradle, groovy, jvm

I'm writing a Gradle plugin in Scala.

To allow me to configure the plugin and associated tasks via a Gradle DSL I need to be able to invoke methods dynamically (i.e. methods that don't actually exist). If I were writing the plugin in Groovy I'd use `methodMissing` or `propertyMissing` as described [here](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing.html).

In Scala I can invoke functions dynamically using [dynamic member lookup](http://blog.scalac.io/2015/05/21/dynamic-member-lookup-in-scala.html). This works when invoking the functions from Scala code but I can't seem to find a way to invoke these dynamic functions from Groovy (i.e. when the Scala plugin is used as part of another Gradle project).

Is it possible to utilise Scala's dynamic member lookup from Groovy? Or is this a dead end?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out the answer to my question. In Scala I need to implement the same `methodMissing` and `propertyMissing` functions that I'd implement if I were writing a Groovy class and have the Scala class extend `GroovyObjectSupport` (needed for Gradle integration).

If anyone else is trying to do something similar below are the function signatures in Scala you need to implement:

```
class Foo extends GroovyObjectSupport {
  def methodMissing(m: String, arg: Any): Any = ???
  def propertyMissing(p: String): Any = ???
  def propertyMissing(p: String, v: Any): Any = ???
}
```